# BinaryReader C# - Check if there are bytes left

Tags: c#, binaryreader

I was wondering if there is any method or property that allow us to see if there are available bytes to read in the stream associated to a `BinaryReader` (in my case, it is a NetworkStream, since I am performing a TCP communication).
I have checked the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx) and the only method I have seen is `PeekChar()`, but it only checks if there is a next byte (character), so in case there are many bytes to read, making a `while` loop to increase a counter may be inneficient.

Regarding the TCP communication, the problem is that the application protocol behind the TCP was not defined by me, and I am just trying to figure out how it works! Of course there will be some "length field" that will give me some clues about the bytes to read, but right know I am just checking how it works and this question came to my mind.

Comment: TCP is a streaming protocol... not sure what you mean, but `length` is pretty much the opposite of the definition of `streaming`. `BinaryReader` is just a wrapper around the protocol stream.

Comment: Mmm... I am sorry but I don't understand your point!

Comment: What do you plan to do if there _aren't_ any bytes available right now? That doesn't mean that there isn't more coming...

Comment: The specific problem here with a TCP stream is that, as soon as you have determined that the answer is "no", or that there are 20 bytes available, those answers may no longer be accurate.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe The thing is that if I use a reading method like ReadInt32(), but there are not enough bytes available, it will block my code until it receives more data (of course, I should know beforehand if I really want to read an int32 or not)

Comment: That's a different problem: use a non-blocking (or async) read.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe In that case I should forget about the BinaryReader, right? just use reading methods from the own Stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BinaryReader` itself doesn't have a `DataAvailable` property, but [the `NetworkStream` does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(socket);
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);

while (true)
{
    if (stream.DataAvailable)
    {
        // call reader.ReadBytes(...) like you normally would!
    }
    // do other stuff here!
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

If you don't have a handle to the original NetworkStream at the point where you would call `reader.ReadBytes()`, you can use [the `BaseStream` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.basestream(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
while (true)
{
    NetworkStream stream = reader.BaseStream as NetworkStream;
    if (stream.DataAvailable)
    {
        // call reader.ReadBytes(...) like you normally would!
    }
    // do other stuff here!
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

BinaryReader will block until it reads all bytes required. The only exception is if it detects end of stream. But NetworkStream is an open stream and does not have the end of stream condition. So you can either create class with basic readers (ReadInt, ReadDouble, etc) that uses peek, reads byte by byte and does not block; or use another async technology.